# Allow opening a file with open() only in one process, in c unix programming

Tags: c, file, sockets, unix, server

I'm creating an application client/server. Users registered are located in their specific file. I need that only one process of my client can login with that specific username. So I think that the best way to handle it, it's to forbid the opening of a file if it's just opened by another process, but I don't know how to do it. Suggestions? Thanks!
I have thought about semaphores but I don't think is the best solution....

ok, I'll use flock() thanks! ^^ But after open() what kind of error will give me?

Comment: File-locking is typically something done *without* a server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the system command/shell command called `flock`.

So as you want only one process accessing the open file, you'll be using `LOCK_EX` operation on the file descriptor (Assuming you're using the system call).

Please go through the man pages. `man flock` for shell command and `man 2 flock` for the system call.

Comment: @iharob: that was a weird edit you made there; copy and paste failure?

Comment: @MartijnPieters Ooops ... Indeed ... It did seem weird to me where all the code came from?

Comment: @iharob: when a post looks weird after editing, always check the edit history to see what happened. :-)

Comment: @iharob: in this case the extra text came from [this question you also edited](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29732935/why-garbage-value-in-union-integer); you must've still had it in your clipboard.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [flock()](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/flock.2.html) and set an exclusive lock on that file. This will prevent other processes than the one that set the lock to open the file.

Answer (score 0):

If you have one multi-threaded server (but one process) that handles all the users, then it's best to just keep track of logged in users in memory. In that case, you can use mutexes (a type of semaphore) to make sure that one connection locks access to a particular user profile, and every time a new user connects, you can query your data structure. For instance, if you're using pthreads, you can define an array as follows, assuming each user has a sequential integer ID:

```
pthread_mutex_t YourServer::accountLocks[numberOfUsers]
```

If you have multiple separate processes that for some reason can't share memory, then lock files are an option. In that case, you'll have to be careful not to introduce race conditions, and you can use something like [flock](http://linux.die.net/man/2/flock).

Comment: you're not the only one to wonder. [Relevant meta question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/290772/how-to-detect-users-that-downvote-all-other-answers)